# I want to know how and what libraries used in creating android studio profiler plugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin in intelliJ that will draw live graph exactly same as android studio profiler but i'am unable to find open source for android studio profiler, I want to know which library they are using to plot live graph.

Only thing i could make out till now is they are using javaswing to display the graph in toolswindow. I tried using JFreeChart but when i add new datapoints its xaxis size reduces causing my graph to become compact and also its hard to enable scrolling

Comment: Android Studio and the used IntelliJ platform are closed source programs. You can see all open source libraries used by Android Studio in the about box.